# ipad: Easy way to customise the UIActionSheet look & feel to be like the one in Safari?

Tags: ipad, uiactionsheet

This is the default look & feel of `UIActionSheet`.

[image]

The border of the view is very thick with black colors, the overall looking is very bold and heavy.

This is the one Safari has

[image]

You can see that the border is very thin, and overall looking is more light and simpler

Can someone tell me how do i customise the default `UIActionSheet` view to the one in Safari? make it more simpler and lighter?

Thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHat you're looking for is the UIPopover class, where you can insert whatever views you want, like an ActionSheet for example.

See http://sdktoday.net/2010/04/creating-a-uipopover/ to learn how to create an UIPopover.

Hope this helps :)